# Determine rotation angles from one plane to another

Tags: c++, vector, 3d, rotation, geometry

Let's have 2 vectors v1, v2 in a 3D space.
v1 and v2 belongs to 2 different planes P1,P2.
v1 and v2 intersect at point p(xp,yp,zp)
v1:p->a and v2:p->b where a(xa,ya,za) and b(xb,yb,zb) are 2 known points in P1 and P2 respectively.
The angle "theta" between P1 and P2 is known and could be computed using the three points p,a,b

Here is my question:
I need to know which rotation should i apply to v1 in order to coincide with v2 ?
In other words:
v1 is defined by a start point p(xp,yp,zp) and a direction (alpha,beta,gamma)
v1:[xp,yp,zp,alpha,beta,gamma].
v2 is defined by the same start point p(xp,yp,zp) and a direction (alpha1,beta1,gamma1)
v2[xp,yp,zp,alpha1,beta1,gamma1]
so which modification to alpha,beta, and maybe gamma should be done to get alpha1, beta1, and however gamma1

Thanks in advance

Lara

Comment: You should be more precise about your actual problem is. It is hard to understand how your geometry is assembled. 3D Vectors are just tuples of 3 scalars. They aren't points and not rays either. Do you mean that the 2 vectors are the normals of the planes or are they points in the planes? Using mathematical expressions could help a lot.

Comment: You are right! v1 and v2 are rays and not vectors they are defined by a starting point p and a direction in the 3D space. They are not the normals of the planes. a and b are points in the planes

Comment: So simply put you have:
A point p: as origin of
two rays v1 and v2
and two planes P1 and P2 that intersect with the two rays but the direction of the rays aren't the normals of the planes, so they don't hit them orthogonally. And you want to let v2 be the same as v1. Then just subtract one from the other. But what do the planes have to do with all this? Should one of them follow the transformation of v2? And should the geometric relationship between each ray and plane be preserved?

Answer (score 1):

Look like you want to find out the rotation matrix [M] so that {v2} =[M]{v1}, where both {v1} and {v2} are unit vectors of 3x1 and [M] is a 3x3 matrix. You can refer to the Wikipedia page for Rotation Matrix [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix). Scroll down to the section "Rotation Matrix from axis and angle", where it shows the rotation matrix about a given axis by a given angle. For your case, the axis will be the cross product vector v1 X v2 and the angle will be the angle between v1 and v2, which can be obtained as acos( v1 dot v2 ).